# MySql - Finding duplicates and deleting them in two tables

Tags: mysql

I have a very big amount of data on my tables (table 1 and table 2) so I am asking this simple question because I want to have the most efficient way to do this:

How can I delete all the entries from table 1, which are also in table 2 (identified by attribute 'atribxy'). So there will be only exclusive entries in table 1 and in table 2. How can I achieve this in the most efficent way using a SQL-query?

Comment: What have you tried so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do so:

**Using JOIN**

```
DELETE table2
FROM  table2
INNER JOIN  table1 ON table1.atribxy = table2.atribxy
```

**Using IN**

```
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE atribxy IN (SELECT atribxy FROM table1)
```

**Using EXIST**

```
DELETE FROM table2 t2 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.atribxy = t2.atribxy)
```

Comment: @Vasan what is the correct syntax to the first query ? And IN, JOINs and ZXIST may have the same performance and may not depending on the strecture of the tables.